# IE8: document.write to opened window gives me "Access is denied"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**:Edit start:** 
I have found the cause but not yet the solution. In my original page I have the following line:

```
document.domain = "<mydomain>";
```

This appears to be the culprit as "mydomain" is different from my local server. Will now try to find a solution.

**:Edit end:**

I have this js in my code:

```
function prnt() {
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'width=1000,height=700');

    printWindow.document.open();
    printWindow.document.write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');
    printWindow.document.write(...);
    printWindow.document.write('</html>');

    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();

    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}
```

It goes without saying that it works like a charm in Chrome (as always). The problem is IE8 where I an "Access is denied" on my first attempt to call

```
printWindow.document.write(...);
```

Can anyone help me out here?

I have tried with

```
var printWindow = window.open('**#**', 'Print', 'width=1000,height=700');
```

and I have tried without

```
printWindow.document.open();
```

All in vain... :-(

Comment: It did work on my pc . Can you post the console ertor anf your document and browser mode ?

Comment: The only error I get is "Access is denied.". From debugging I can see that as soon as I try to access printWindow.document I get the error. In terms of browser mode I'm not sure what u mean. I my page's OnPreInit(...) I have this: Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=Edge");. That's pretty much it.

Comment: What security zone is the site in question running in? (Right-click the page and choose Properties)

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same problem, the problem is [Cross Frame Scripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028(VS.85).aspx) Make sure the `window.open('//'+window.location.hostname..` To make it work.

Answer (score -1):

It did work for me :

[image]

With this code : (same as yours)

```
 var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'width=1000,height=700');

    printWindow.document.open();
    printWindow.document.write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');
    printWindow.document.write('<body>aaaaaaaa</body>');
    printWindow.document.write('</html>');

    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();

  //  printWindow.print();
   // printWindow.close();
```

(pure ie8)

Comment: Now that's weird. The client I'm working for atm is a bank that has gone through all sorts of hoops to prevent the use of tabs in IE8 and forced the compatibility view option to be enabled. Can this be causing the behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: Q : did you actually use that name `window.open('**#**'` ? please try a regular string (just for testing). i will test it later with compatibility mode.

Comment: No no :-) First I tried with '' and then with '#'. The latter just reloads the page I'm coming from. I was just trying to highlight the pound sign :-)